# getting error 404 on a valid url with get_headers and get_meta_tags

Tags: php, get-headers

could someone explain me why with a valid url and visible in browser I get HTTP request failed! `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` with `get_headers` and `get_meta_tags`?

the url that I'm trying to access is

```
http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/icde/2011/8959/00/05767935-abs.html
```

but by the same site I could get what I neede in this url:

```
http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/cgc/2013/5114/00/5114a201-abs.html
```

Comment: They could be sending a 404 based on the user agent to prevent scripts from touching the pages.

Comment: good, the same domain, I was doing it in the same browser. I tried with this solution but still I get error 404.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439272/file-get-contents-returns-404-when-url-is-opened-with-the-browser-and-url-is-val](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439272/file-get-contents-returns-404-when-url-is-opened-with-the-browser-and-url-is-val)

Comment: Well, when I test it I get a `200` which means no problems. http://codepad.viper-7.com/q9cqHa

Comment: yes, I've seen your link, too strange because I still having the error 404 doesn't matter what I try to do, get_headers or get_meta_tag sneds me that error.

--

EDIT: the issue could be matched by that my site is in godaddy and I'm using Yii for that job?

Comment: Can't reproduce that. this: `var_dump(get_headers('http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/icde/2011/8959/00/05767935-abs.html'));` gave me [that](http://pastebin.com/pq6Qd2Yk)

Comment: Try getting a different url from a different domain. Perhaps all urls are returning a 404. Also, maybe try getting just their main page at `www.computer.org`. If either is the case, I would head to godaddy support.

Comment: @hek2mgl what I get is: **get_meta_tags(http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/icde/2011/8959/00/05767935-abs.htm) [<a href='function.get-meta-tags'>function.get-meta-tags</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found**

Comment: Is the server behind a proxy?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn as I mentioned, with http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/cgc/2013/5114/00/5114a201-abs.html I can get meta tags, with others I can get meta tags, but is specifically with http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/icde/2011/8959/00/05767935-abs.html that I cannot. 

thnx for all answers. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl as I know and what I can see in the panel, not.

Comment: have you shell access to the server?

Comment: sorry, not, currently I don't have shell access.

I tried in localhost and the results are the same :\